# MapController, OSMdroid, zoomToSpan() freezes application

Tags: android, zooming, android-mapview, osmdroid

I use OSMdroid to display an offline map. The MapView is placed inside a Fragment. I would like to zoom the map to cover two points (top_left, bottom_right). Currently when I call zoomToSpan() in onViewCreated() the app freezes. I have tried using BoundingBoxE6 and latitude, longitude span but nothing changes.

```
BoundingBoxE6 bb = new BoundingBoxE6(
    LocationConstants.TOP_LEFT_LATITUDE,
    LocationConstants.TOP_LEFT_LONGITUDE,
    LocationConstants.BOTTOM_RIGHT_LATITUDE,
    LocationConstants.BOTTOM_RIGHT_LONGITUDE);
```

or

```
 int latitudeSpan = (int) Math.abs(LocationConstants.TOP_LEFT_LATITUDE*1E6  - LocationConstants.BOTTOM_RIGHT_LATITUDE*1E6);
 int longitudeSpan = (int) Math.abs(LocationConstants.TOP_LEFT_LONGITUDE*1E6 - LocationConstants.BOTTOM_RIGHT_LONGITUDE*1E6);
```

give the same results.